# How can I have the @ and the .com on ios keyboard in my app

Tags: ios

How can I have the @ and the .com on ios keyboard in my app.

It seems to be only one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the email keyboard you can just hold the '.' button and it will display a list of options for you. So if you're wanting this for the user to enter an email address you should use the @ symbol only version.

Answer (score 0):

You can always customize the keyboard.  Either entirely, or by adding an accessory view to an existing one.  Here's some good info on doing so:  http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/